# Passing a variable value from jquery to uploadify php file

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-plugins, uploadify

jquery

```
    function uploadpho(){
    $foldername=$("#storeloyaltyid").val();
    $('#uploadpho').uploadify({
        uploader:urljs+"/jslib/clUploadify.swf",
        cancelImage:urljs+"/image/cancel.png",
        buttonImage:urljs+"/image/browse_button.png",
        'scriptData'     :{folder:$("#storeloyaltyid").val()},//photoxyz
        uploadUrl:urljs+"/jslib/uploadify.php",
                    formData :  jQuery.parseJSON('{"folder":"'+$("#storeloyaltyid").val()+'"}'),
        onComplete: function(event,status,data,imgs){   
        //alert($foldername);
            $("#uploadpho").val(imgs);
        },

        onRemove:function(event,imgs){
            $("#uploadpho").val(imgs);
        }
    });
}
```

Uploadify php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_FILES)) {

$filename = $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$filetmpname = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES["Filedata"]["type"];
$fileSizeMB = ($_FILES["Filedata"]["size"] / 1024 / 1024);
$targetPath=$_POST['folder'];//not able to get the value here??
    if($targetPath==''){
    $targetPath='tmp';
     mkdir('../uploaded_photos/' .$targetPath, 0755, true);// comes to loop and creates a tmp folder
  }else{
     mkdir('../uploaded_photos/' .$targetPath, 0755, true);
}
// Place file on server, into the images folder
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "../uploaded_photos/".$targetPath.'/'.$filename);
//echo $filename;
}elseif($_POST['d']){
$filename = $_POST['d'];
$dFile = "../uploaded_photos/".$filename;
unlink($dFile);

    }
    ?>
```

I need to know how to pass a value from jquery uploadify to uploadify.php in order to fetch the folder name

Comment: should `scriptData` be `formData`?  http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/

Comment: used both formData as well as Scriptdata... and i found the solution... i used a new uploadify 3.1... and it is able to pass the value!!!

Comment: awesome, you might add that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It had this problem in old version of uploadify, Later upgrading to `uploadify 3.1` i was able to fetch it through scriptData.